# How to install flutter and dart in Android Studio and InttelliJ?

Tags: android, intellij-idea, dart, flutter, flutter-dependencies

I am facing issues with installation. I get the following when I run 
flutter doctor

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel beta, v0.4.4, on Mac OS X 10.11.6 15G19009, locale en)
    • Flutter version 0.4.4 at /Users/divyakrishnan/Development/flutter
    • Framework revision f9bb4289e9 (11 days ago), 2018-05-11 21:44:54 -0700
    • Engine revision 06afdfe54e
    • Dart version 2.0.0-dev.54.0.flutter-46ab040e58

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK 27.0.3)
    • Android SDK at /Users/divyakrishnan/Library/Android/sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-27, build-tools 27.0.3
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio 3.0 Preview.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-915-b01)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[!] iOS toolchain - develop for iOS devices
    ✗ Xcode installation is incomplete; a full installation is necessary for iOS development.
      Download at: https://developer.apple.com/xcode/download/
      Or install Xcode via the App Store.
      Once installed, run:
        sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    ✗ libimobiledevice and ideviceinstaller are not installed. To install, run:
        brew install --HEAD libimobiledevice
        brew install ideviceinstaller
    ✗ ios-deploy not installed. To install:
        brew install ios-deploy
    ✗ CocoaPods not installed.
        CocoaPods is used to retrieve the iOS platform side's plugin code that responds to your plugin usage on the Dart side.
        Without resolving iOS dependencies with CocoaPods, plugins will not work on iOS.
        For more info, see https://flutter.io/platform-plugins
      To install:
        brew install cocoapods
        pod setup

[✓] Android Studio
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio 3.0 Preview.app/Contents
    ✗ Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    ✗ Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-915-b01)

[!] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2018.1.4)
    • IntelliJ at /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app
    ✗ Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    ✗ Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
    • For information about installing plugins, see
      https://flutter.io/intellij-setup/#installing-the-plugins

[!] Connected devices
    ! No devices available
```

**I do not see the flutter or dart plugin in Android Studio 3.0 and IntelliJ.**

Comment: Open up the android studio go to File -> Project -> Plugins and install flutter plugin there

Comment: And also you dont need both IDEA and go to the link that provided by Flutter doctor(iOS toolchain)

Answer (score 6):

The plugins are not installed by default with Android Studio or IntelliJ. You need to install them yourself using the instructions from [this page](https://flutter.io/get-started/editor/#androidstudio):

**Install the Flutter and Dart plugins**

> Flutter is supported by two plugins:
>
> - The Flutter plugin powers Flutter developer workflows (running, debugging, hot reload, etc.).
> - The Dart plugin offers code analysis (code validation as you type, code completions, etc.).

**To install these:**

1. Start the Android Studio.
2. Open plugin preferences (**Preferences>Plugin**s on macOS, **File>Settings>Plugins** on Windows & Linux).
3. Select Browse repositories…, select the Flutter plugin and click **install**.
4. Click **Yes** when prompted to install the Dart plugin.
5. Click **Restart** when prompted.

Answer (score 4):

Just follow these steps:

1. Go to Plugins.
   [image: Plugin]
2. Browse Repositories.
   [image: Click Browse repositories]
3. Search for flutter.
   [image: Search flutter]
4. Tap on Install (a dialog will pop regarding dart dependency. click Yes).
   [image: Agree to install dart]
5. Once the installation is finished restart android studio.
   [image: Restart android studio]

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

I had the same problem and these are the steps to solve my problem (**[Install the Flutter and Dart plugins](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/editor?tab=androidstudio)**):

1. Start Android Studio.
2. Open plugin preferences (**Configure > Plugins** as of `v3.6.3.0` or `later`).

[image]

> Note: Prior to v3.6.3.0, should follow:  Open plugin preferences
> (**Preferences > Plugins** on macOS, **File >
> Settings > Plugins** on Windows & Linux)

3. Select the Flutter plugin and click **Install**.

[image]

4. Click **Yes** when prompted to install the `Dart` plugin.

[image]

5. Click **Restart** when prompted.

---

Run `flutter doctor`. You should get this output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One of the most import thing always " RUN AS ADMINISTRATOR " you IDE i.e Android .. etc.
for flutter to avoid several errors.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Installing Flutter and Dart Plugins into Android Studio is very easy--
 Follow the steps to install-

1. Click on ***Configure --> Plugins***
2. Browse **Flutter** repository from Search box
3. Click on **install** button
4. Click on **Yes** to install **Dart** plugin from Alter prompt
5. After completing all process ***Restart Android Studio*** to activate ***plugins***

For more information [Click here to find detail steps with graphical inteface](http://www.studyzone24.com/blogs/1-installing-flutter-in-android-studio-step-by-step)

Answer (score 0):

This is the step for flutter install the Android Studio:

```
1.Go to Settings->Plugin->Install Flutter and Dart->Restart Android Studio
2.Download  the flutter sdk
3.In the environment Variable->User Variable->
ANDROID_HOME F:\AndroidSDK(Paste your Android SDK Path)
Path:F:\AndroidSDk;(Paste your Android SDK Path)
     c:\ProgramFiles\Java\jdk\1.8.0_20\bin;(Paste your jdk Path)
     c:\Users\Desktop\flutter\bin;(Paste your Flutter SDK Path)
4.Git install at c:\ProgramFiles\Git
5.Open Gitbash
$flutter doctor
$flutter doctor --android-licenses
Accept the licences Y Y Y Y
Make sure your Device should be connected your PC
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution myself, so there is no link for proof or details.

I tried installing Dart and Flutter plugin via Android Studio (`File - Settings - Plugins - Market Place`). Every time after install it showed `Restart IDE`. After restart every time Android Studio use to show `Disable Flutter plugin or install Dart`.
After many attempts (installing Dart via above option), what I did I went into

```
*\.AndroidStudio4.0\system\plugins
```

copied `flutter-intellij.zip` and `Dart-*.*.zip` files into

```
*\.AndroidStudio4.0\config\plugins
```

and **just unzipped these 2 files ( used extract here option)** and launched android studio, **the error was gone** and Android Studio showed some data collection message.

Now I can see `File -> New -> New Flutter Project ...`