# Issue in Flutter setup

Tags: java, android, flutter

I can't fix the Flutter problem after I try to set up the platform
and problem as shows here :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/uddfn.png

Comment: Did you try answers for this question? https://stackoverflow.com/q/49758849/10595176

Comment: You might need to install Flutter and Dart plugins which are pending,

Comment: make sure you have installed the plugin,also run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` like in the picture,then try run a sample project or newly created project,even if you installed the dart and flutter plugin the red tick mark will be present everybody have same problem but try to run a project,i have the same problem but i can run project without any problem@KLer Art

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 things that was missing in you environment :

1. Flutter plugin in Android Studio
2. Dart plugin in Android Studio (required by Flutter)
3. Agreement for Android Studio

Just install android studio and those flutter / dart plugin then you are good to go :
https://developer.android.com/studio

Answer by another CKE on 2018 :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/52817038/6483547

Answer (score 1):

Try the below steps:

1. Open your terminal
2. type `flutter doctor --android-licenses`
3. press `y` to accept, this process may occurred several times.

Answer (score 0):

well, first of all.

You are missing the flutter and dart addon for android studio.
To install this:

> 1.Go to: android studio > settings > plugins
>
> 2.search the flutter plugin and install (dart should come packaged with it if i remember correctly, else youll have to do the same for
> the dart plugin)

in the Command Console you'll need to run the flutter doctor command. The command also mentioned a --android-licences part that comes right after flutter doctor.

after that you should be fine. If not, look up any tutorial on youtube:

> i'd reccomend:
> -https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GLSG_Wh_YWc&list=PL8gumPF20ihcoYHvyQnZOupK5-pplnDyQ&index=4
> (kinda long, but covers most of the basics)
> -https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z2ugnpCQuyw&list=PLSzsOkUDsvdtl3Pw48-R8lcK2oYkk40cm&index=4
> (part of another tutorial)